# Import Errors from Excel to Access Using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport Method

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm getting some import errors when importing data from Excel in to Access.

I'm using the `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, ...` method to do the import.

The column of data that is failing contains a mixture of number-only entries and strings. It's the string entries that are failing to import.

Is there something I can do to the data in this column of the Excel spreadsheet to ensure it gets across to Access in its entirety?

Comment: Are you importing into a new table or an existing table?

Comment: The existing table gets deleted first via `DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, ...` prior to be being recreated with the same name via `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, ...`

Comment: Does it work if you empty the table instead of deleting the table before `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`?

Comment: @HansUp Unfortunately that does not work; I tried it. I did a manual import first (and specified the column as Text) to create the table, then emptied the table and did a `.TransferSpreadsheet` back into it. The numeric values imported into the (text) column, but the alphanumeric values were omitted (left as Null) and logged as ImportErrors.

Answer (score 1):

While your `Excel.Application` code from your previous question is in there "counting rows" it could also inspect the cell for that column in the first data row. If it is numeric, your code could glue an apostrophe (`'`) at the beginning to force it to be a label, and then save the Excel file. Then, when Access' `TransferSpreadsheet` method looks at the first row it will decide that the column is text, not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I found something approaching a workaround:

1. Sort your offending column in Excel so that your numerics appear as the top-most group and your alphanumerics are at the bottom.
2. Highlight all your numerics now grouped in the column
3. Go to Data > Text to Columns
4. Wizard Page 1: Select "Delimited"
5. Wizard Page 2: Tick "Tab"
6. Wizard Page 3: Select "Text" and finish

Numbers will be stored as text with the leading apostrophe and should import ok in Access

[Source](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/three-ways-to-convert-numbers-to-text-HA001136619.aspx)

There's probably a better way of doing this though if anyone wants to chip-in.

Comment: As per my answer, you don't need to change *all* of the numerics, just the one in the first data row. When Access inspects a spreadsheet to "guess" the column types it looks at "the first couple of data rows" (I've seen the number '8' mentioned), so as long as there's one alphanumeric very near the top of the column then the column will *probably* end up as Text. (I say "probably, because if the alphanumerics look like Dates, then... *who knows?*)

Comment: sorry - I should have said that I tried that, but it would only import the numerics as exponential notation as text... for some reason.